# Can we make a slight modification to the "short, self contained, correct example" off-topic close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Currently that close reason reads:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

[Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson), the author of the SSCCE document linked in that text, pointed out [in a blog comment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1#comment-80023) that this text implies that a poster *must* provide an SSCCE, which mildly contradicts a portion of that document.

> Let us assume you are indeed genuine in your learning, you have a huge, complex system with an occasional, unpredictable bug, and you have searched the FAQ & Group, studied the manual or documentation and not produced an answer.
>
> Feel free to describe the problem to the group; perhaps it is a basic misunderstanding on your part that can easily be cleared up.
>
> I am not proposing that every single problem needs a SSCCE in order to be solved. I am also not suggesting an example is, or should be, compulsory.
>
> It will, however, make people much more likely to help, and will therefore increase the chance of finding a solution.

Should we modify that close reason to remove the contradiction with the linked document using Andrew's suggestion?

> Questions concerning problems with code you’ve written must describe the specific problem and should ideally include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance on the latter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is that that close reason shouldn't be selected unless it's clear that a proper code sample *is* required, given the context of the question.  If the particular question being asked can be made into a good question without needing to provide code then that is not the proper close reason to use.